Sending HID Command "System Microphone Mute" via ESP32 BLE
I am trying to send the "System Microphone Mute" HID command with a ESP32 to a Windows PC.
Unfortunatelly I cannot get it to work.
The USB HID protocol I am refering to is:
https://usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_5.pdf#page=44&zoom=100,57,57
My test Arduino code is the following:
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include "BLE2902.h"
#include "BLEHIDDevice.h"
#include "HIDTypes.h"

static const uint8_t REPORT_MAP[] = {
    0x05, 0x01,           // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x80,           // Usage (System Control)
    0xA1, 0x01,           // Collection (Application)
    0x85, 0x01,           //   Report ID (1)
    0x15, 0x00,           //   Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x01,           //   Logical Maximum (1)
    0x75, 0x01,           //   Report Size (1)
    0x95, 0x01,           //   Report Count (1)
    0x09, 0xA9,           //   Usage (System Microphone Mute)
    0x81, 0x06,           //   Input (Data, Variable, Relative)
    0xC0                  // End Collection
};


BLEHIDDevice* hid;
BLECharacteristic* input;
bool connected = false;

class ServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* server) override {
        connected = true;
    }
    
    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* server) override {
        connected = false;
    }
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Starting BLE Microphone Mute Controller");

    // Initialize BLE
    BLEDevice::init("BLE Mic Mute");
    BLEServer* server = BLEDevice::createServer();
    server->setCallbacks(new ServerCallbacks());

    // Create HID device
    hid = new BLEHIDDevice(server);
    input = hid->inputReport(1);

    // Set HID info
    hid->manufacturer()->setValue("Espressif");
    hid->pnp(0x02, 0xe502, 0xa111, 0x0210);
    hid->hidInfo(0x00, 0x02);

    // Security
    BLESecurity* security = new BLESecurity();
    security->setAuthenticationMode(ESP_LE_AUTH_BOND);

    // Set report map
    hid->reportMap((uint8_t*)REPORT_MAP, sizeof(REPORT_MAP));
    hid->startServices();

    // Advertising
    BLEAdvertising* advertising = server->getAdvertising();
    advertising->setAppearance(0x03C4); // Generic HID Device
    advertising->addServiceUUID(hid->hidService()->getUUID());
    advertising->start();

    Serial.println("Waiting for connection...");
}

void toggleMicMute() {
    if (!connected) return;
    
    uint8_t mute[] = {0x01}; // Bit 0 set for Mic Mute
    input->setValue(mute, sizeof(mute));
    input->notify();
    
    delay(50);
    
    uint8_t release[] = {0x00}; // Release button
    input->setValue(release, sizeof(release));
    input->notify();
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        char cmd = Serial.read();
        if (cmd == 'm') {
            Serial.println("Toggling microphone mute");
            toggleMicMute();
        }
    }
    delay(50);
}

Any recommendations how to improve?

I don't see anything obviously wrong, but you could try changing the Input descriptor item to Absolute instead of Relative (makes more sense to me - you want to set the value rather than nudge it up or down)
